# How do I get rid of this TypeError, and why is it occurring given that I am simply reassigning a value in a list?

Tags: python, debugging, typeerror, tic-tac-toe

Code:

http://pastie.org/1961455

Trackback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\COMPAQ\Desktop\NoughtsCrosses.py", line 149, in <module>
    main ()
  File "C:\Users\COMPAQ\Desktop\NoughtsCrosses.py", line 144, in main
    move = computer_move(computer, board, human)
  File "C:\Users\COMPAQ\Desktop\NoughtsCrosses.py", line 117, in computer_move
    board[i] = computer
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

As you can see for in my tic-tac-toe program, the board[i] = computer line in the computer_move function is the one (if I am reading this right) causing the error. But if I know this right, item assignment is allowed in lists, and I create a local copy of "board" for my function so that I can reassign values and whatnot within the function...

Any input at all would be greatly appreciated. This is my first serious piece of code, so if the function in question looks too mangled

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
def computer_move (computer, board, human):
    best = (4,0,8,2,6,1,3,5,7)
    board = board [:]
    for i in legal_moves(board):
        board[i] = computer
        if winner(board) == computer:
            return i
        board = EMPTY
```

At the end of the function, you assign `EMPTY` to `board`, but `EMPTY` is an empty string, as defined on line 4. I assume you must have meant `board[i] = EMPTY`.

Comment: Got it! Thanks so much, man. It feels good to have written my first, obviously it looks like I need to get better at reading my code and debugging, but I'm not complaining for now. Thanks everyone that answered.

Answer (score 4):

In line 120, you reassign board to `EMPTY` (ie an empty string). So from that point on, board is no longer a list, so you can't assign `board[i]`. Not quite sure what you meant to do there.

Generally, your code would greatly benefit from using object-orientation - with Board as a class, keeping track of its member squares.

Comment: I haven't gotten around to learning classes yet, but thanks. I will look into that.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `board` is a string. I get the same error when I do this:

```
>>> s = ''
>>> s[1] = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```